# Read comma separated text file into HashMap where file has same key in multiple lines Java

Tags: java

I m trying to read the date as key from a comma separated file and MeterID(Which is the first item in the file) as the value. But my problem is, the file has the same date in multiple lines and when I m trying to read the file into a hashmap, I m getting extra null value with every key.

**Data in the file is as follow**

```
MeterID,ServiceLocationID,ESIID,ReadingDate,ReadingTime,kWh,rxKWh,KVARHImprt,KVARhExprt,kWhImprtRateA,kWhImprtRateB,kWhExprtRateA,kWhExprtRateB,kVARhImprtRateA,kVARhImprtRateB,kVARhExprtRateA,kVARhExprtRateB,kVARhTotalRateA,kVARhTotalRateB,ExprtkVARhTotalRateA,ExprtkVARhTotalRateB
 1182798,,,13/04/2018,12:00:00AM,12391.000,0.000,,,6196.991,6194.366,0.074,0.000,1119.000,1132.000,0.000,0.000,,,,
 1182799,,,14/04/2018,12:00:00AM,690.000,0.000,,,348.468,342.449,0.074,0.000,95.000,96.000,0.000,0.000,,,,
 1182800,,,15/04/2018,12:00:00AM,2863.000,0.000,,,1133.865,1729.365,0.074,0.000,37.000,21.000,156.000,135.000,,,,
 1182801,,,16/04/2018,12:00:00AM,1578.000,0.000,,,1065.586,512.603,0.074,0.000,225.000,199.000,27.000,14.000,,,, 1182802,,,17/04/2018,12:00:00AM,2059.000,0.000,,,716.310,1343.338,0.074,0.000,58.000,85.000,63.000,78.000,,,,
 1182803,,,18/04/2018,12:00:00AM,1824.000,0.000,,,755.363,1069.038,0.074,0.000,234.000,289.000,65.000,73.000,,,, 1182804,,,18/04/2018,12:00:00AM,1824.000,0.000,,,755.363,1069.038,0.074,0.000,234.000,289.000,65.000,73.000,,,,
```

**See below code to read data from the file into a hashmap**

```
String filePath = "electric-enhanced_0000_201804130555.txt";
    String delimiter = ",";
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath)).skip(1)) {
        lines.filter(line -> line.contains(delimiter)).forEach(line -> map.put(line.split(delimiter)[3],
                line.split(delimiter)[0] + "," + map.get(line.split(delimiter)[3])));
    }

    System.out.println(map);
```

**Excepted result is**

> {15/04/2018=1182800, 14/04/2018=1182799, 17/04/2018=1182802,
>   18/04/2018=1182804,1182803, 16/04/2018=1182801, 13/04/2018=1182798}

**Actual result is** - null is coming with every key which i want to exclude

> {15/04/2018=1182800,null, 14/04/2018=1182799,null,
>   17/04/2018=1182802,null, 18/04/2018=1182804,1182803,null,
>   16/04/2018=1182801,null, 13/04/2018=1182798,null}

Comment: remove map.get(line.split(delimiter)[3])

Comment: @Hades if i remove this. My output is {15/04/2018=1182800, 14/04/2018=1182799, 17/04/2018=1182802, 18/04/2018=1182804, 16/04/2018=1182801, 13/04/2018=1182798} which clearly missing multiple values for 18/04/2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to write:

```java
lines.stream().filter(line -> line.contains(delimiter)).forEach(line -> map.put(line.split(delimiter)[3],
                    line.split(delimiter)[0]));
```

You may also want to replace your `HashMap` with for example `org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap` which will let you store multiple values under the same key.

So:

```java
Map<String, String> map = new MultiValueMap();
```

I added one line to your test data and now date 18/04/2018 appears twice, and output is as
{15/04/2018=[1182800], 14/04/2018=[1182799], **18/04/2018=[1182803, 1182804]**, 16/04/2018=[1182801], 13/04/2018=[1182798]}

Comment: I tried this lines.filter(line -> line.contains(delimiter)).forEach(line -> map.put(line.split(delimiter)[3],
                    line.split(delimiter)[0])); i got this output {15/04/2018=1182800, 14/04/2018=1182799, 17/04/2018=1182802, 18/04/2018=1182804, 16/04/2018=1182801, 13/04/2018=1182798} where key 18/04/2018 is missing one more value.

Comment: yes, key=value1,value2 something like this or what you have shown is also fine for me.

Comment: thanks, it worked. '{15/04/2018=[1182800], 14/04/2018=[1182799], 17/04/2018=[1182802], 18/04/2018=[1182803, 1182804], 16/04/2018=[1182801], 13/04/2018=[1182798]}' this is the output.

Comment: I just define like `org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap map = new org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap();` Still it worked.

Comment: Yes, it will still work **but** don't do like this. It's better to use Map as a reference type because if you want to swap implementation, like in our case, it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add a check for null value. Here is the snippet

```
map.put(line.split(delimiter)[3],map.get(line.split(delimiter)[3])==null?line.split(delimiter)[0]:
                    line.split(delimiter)[0] + "," + map.get(line.split(delimiter)[3])));
```